# What was the Chola kings ancestry?

Tags: ancient-history, india

Chola King [Rajendra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajendra_Chola_I) Chola's [copper plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_copper-plate_inscriptions) indicate that the Cholas were descendants of the [Solar Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_dynasty) Kings of India. Are there any other evidences available and is there a dynasty tree available?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this period, but Wikipedia says, "In Indian mythology, the Solar dynasty or the Ikshvaku dynasty was founded by the legendary king Ikshvaku" - which suggests that the Solar Dynasty is a mythological construct rather than a historical construct.  That would present complications for finding confirming sources.